# What does it mean that lower central series terminate?

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition, lie-algebras, nilpotence

The definition of nilpotent Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ says that its lower central series terminate at the zero subalgebra.

The lower central series is the $\mathfrak{g}$, then scalar product of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$, then $\mathfrak{g}$ product with the former etc. etc. (The definition can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_Lie_algebra).)

If some member of this series is zero, then the Lie algebra is nilpotent.

My question is, what is the interpretation of the lower central series terminating to zero?

I only know nilpotence of matrices, where the matrix on the power of some positive integer is zero. How to connect the various definitions of nilpotence - for groups, matrices, algebras etc.? Why do we need this definition and what does it saying in layman terms about the given structure?

Comment: Take the nilpotent Lie algebra $L$ of strictly upper-triangular matrices of size $n$ (if you want, $n=3$ or $n=4$) and compute $[L,L]$, $[L,[L,L]]$ and so on yourself.  This gives you a concrete understanding about nilpotency "in layman terms". The zeros in the matrices get more and more, and you can see how we end up (terminate) with the zero matrix finally.

Comment: The definition of a nilpotent Lie algebra $L$ matches with the definition of a (connected and simply connected) nilpotent Lie group having $L$ as its Lie algebra.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you! Maybe my question should be more about the nilpotence itself - what does nilpotence tell you and why is it so important

Comment: The answer is "easy". For Lie algebras in characteristic zero we have the so-called Levi decomposition into the semidirect product of a *semisimple* algebra and a *solvable* one. Understanding the solvable ones basically amounts to understanding the nilpotent Lie algebras.